# Generic function wrapping and type inferrence in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I want to have a function that wraps another function, for purposes of adjusting arguments a little:

```js
type WrappedFunction<P> = (props: P, children?: string[]) => void
type NonWrappedFunction<P> = (props: P, children: string[]) => void

const wrapFunction = <P>(rawFn: NonWrappedFunction<P>): WrappedFunction<P> => {
    return (props, children) => rawFn(props, children ?? [])
}
```

And then I may pass generic function to that wrapper function, which also works alright:

```js
const wrappedFunction = wrapFunction(<T>(props: {val: T}) => {})
// wrappedFunction is <T>(props: {val: T}, children?: string[]) => void , which is right
```

But if I change return type of wrapper function to add an overload that does not use generic argument `P`, then I'll have compilation errors:

```js
// if I change WrappedFunction to this
type WrappedFunction<P> = ((props: P, children?: string[]) => void) & ((children?: string[]) => void)
// then I'll have TypeScript error about inability to infer props type here:
const wrappedFunction = wrapFunction(<T>(props: {val: T}) => {})
```

It works like this even with simplier types; for example, changing wrapper definition to this

```js
const wrapFunction = <P>(rawFn: NonWrappedFunction<P>): void => {
```

will result in exact same errors.

So, TypeScript uses return type of wrapper function to infer generic argument. But why? And how to avoid it?

I tried inlining the types, in hope that maybe it's just too complex and typescript gaves up inferrence at some point. I also discovered that if non-wrapped function has argument that is just `T` (instead of `{val:T}`), then error does not happen in that place (but the type is still not inferred).

Comment: The only way you will get a modified generic function type coming out of `wrapFunction` is if it uses the support for higher order function type inference as implemented in [ms/TS#30215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215).  But that only works in very specific scenarios, and having the output function be overloaded wrecks it.  I think you can do it [this way instead](https://tsplay.dev/m3V5EN), but such things are fragile in the face of seemingly harmless changes.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Oooh that's smart. Yep, that looks like exactly what I needed. If you write up an answer - I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only facility TypeScript currently has for manipulating [generic function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) is the support for [higher order function inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30215](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215).  That support only applies to very specific scenarios where you pass a generic function as an argument to a higher order generic function.  In particular, it requires that "the called function is a generic function that returns a function type *with a single call signature* [emphasis added]".

So if you change the function to return

```
type WrappedFunction<P> = 
  ((props: P, children?: string[]) => void) & ((children?: string[]) => void)
```

it will break, because that's an intersection of two call signatures, not a single call signature.  You can't return an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) and get higher order function inference.

---

Luckily, it happens that you can rephrase `WrappedFunction<P>` to be a single call signature again.  There is conceptually an equivalence between an overloaded function like `{ (...args: A1): R; (...args: A2): R; (...args: A3): T }` and a single function like `{ (...args: A1 | A2 | A3): T }`.  If all your call signatures have the same return type, you can combine them into a single call signature with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types as a rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types).

So that's

```
type WrappedFunction<P> = ((...args:
  [props: P, children?: string[]] |
  [children?: string[]]
) => void)
```

Once you do that, the higher order function inference starts working again:

```
const wrappedFunction = wrapFunction(<T,>(props: { val: T }) => { })
/* const wrappedFunction: <T>(...args: 
     [children?: string[] | undefined] | 
     [props: { val: T; }, children?: string[] | undefined]
   ) => void */
```

---

That happens to work, which is great. But the support for higher order function inference is, as mentioned, only applicable to very specific scenarios, and is thus  *fragile*. Future readers who find themselves needing support for off-label uses should take heed.  It is very easy to make slight changes to `WrappedFunction<>` definition which would break it irreparably.  If you want to add a property to the function, or make the function a method of object, it will likely stop working.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.6&ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBA6gJwIYWgEwGIFcB2BjEASwHscAeABQD4YBeGACgYDpWkEBzAZwC5gYYAbQgJiEXjAoAaGHgAWhADZoEUHAH4eMLiASEcHQQF0jMAD78h8pSrWbtu-YZPAAlHRoA3YoTSvgoJCwAHKkiCjo2PhEpJQ09AwiYhLSsgrKqjhaOnoGxu60Xj5oAXikOjAA7sgQUQQkOHQwlFJUDMiVGFkwoTjhqFCYuPWx1K5a-ZHDMeTUHjAA3paqIFgIjUxJ4lpIOGAy1hlqO3sFNB1diaLiB+m2jerqQkau7khcMLtgwAC+peUgKo1KbRBpNaooOozBhkAAqrSuyS0CxgniQii0sJgPzOi2x-gA9AAqWQAoERQZQhpaOFtVjMdjcLSWARWO6Zew5JzGcwwXBoKAAM30g1MZhgLIEwmuEhRaIxMFhAG5sbcbBzso48mK+TgBcKcKKWbjvL4YESCQFgEA)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to subvert the issue by changing types like this:

```js
type PropsOf<F> = F extends NonWrappedFunction<infer P> ? P : never
type WrappedFunction<F> = ((props: PropsOf<F>, children?: string[]) => void) & ((children: string[]) => void)
function wrapFunction<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(rawFn: F): WrappedFunction<F> {
```

But that's not great, because typechecking of wrapped function becomes weird (and I only just now realised that I have no way to explicitly pass generic parameter at wrapped function call):

```js
const wrappedFunction = wrapFunction(<T extends number>(props: {val: T, defaultVal?: T}) => {})
// this should error, defaultVal is wrong type
wrappedFunction({val: 1 as 1 | 2, defaultVal: 5})
```

So if anyone has better solution - please tell.